# Creating an SQL with subquery Woo Commerce

Tags: sql, woocommerce, subquery

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT o.`order_id`, o.`order_item_name`, 

(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
 pm.`post_id` = o.`order_id`
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') as 'certificate',

 
 
 
 (select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
 pm.`post_id` = o.`order_id`
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') as 'serial'
 
 
 
 
 
 FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` as o,
`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` as om,
`wp_postmeta` as pm
WHERE
o.`order_item_id` = om.`order_item_id`
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.`order_id`
AND
om.`meta_key` = 'bcs'
```

I want to be able to connect the order_item, order_item_meta, and post meta, and the post meta will call out 2 different meta_keys which are 3-serial and 2-certificate on 2 different columns. But when I will do the query, it will say this error

> Blockquote
> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Is there any way to fix this? It may be that the subquery is causing the problems.

Comment: The error is clear. Subqueries in a select statment must return a single value, and some of your subqueries are not behaving this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of your orders return more than one value in your subqueries. You can not use a sintax:

```
select (select ...), (select ...)
```

where the `(select ...)` return more than one value.

If you want to find what orders are behaving this way, you can use the next query.

```
select  pm.`post_id`, pm.`meta_key`
from  `wp_postmeta` as pm
where pm.`meta_key` in ('2-certificate', '3-serial')
group by pm.`post_id`, pm.`meta_key`
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Wow, okay yup I've found the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: If my answer is valid pleas mark it as correct